# Javascript security / cross scripting on same server

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

Have some Javascript that I need to work via the following:

://localhost

://servername

:/www.domainnamefortheserver.com

When I run the script from http://servername with an IFRAME referencing the domain - it does not load.

Is there a way to get the Javascript security model to recognize the server name, localhost and the domain as the same "domain"?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using absolute URLs ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on UNIX you can edit /etc/hosts to give a fake DNS entry for your server.

eg.

127.0.0.1 localhost www.domainnamefortheserver.com

Then you can always connect to it as the correct name even when it's not on the live site yet. Don't try and break the javascript security directly.

This will also work on OSX. Windows works differently, I expect.

Comment: In windows it's the same, you can add an entry to your hosts file located at - \Windows\system32\drivers\etc\

Comment: Thanks. I suspect I'll come looking for that comment in 18 months time when I suddenly discover I need it on Windows!

Comment: Also, the below comments about using relative paths are good, unless you are being limited by some 3rd party software that puts full domains in everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a server-side language to generate the page, you may be able to set the security domain like so:

```
document.domain = $CURRENT_HOSTNAME;
```

So the security domain will be the domain the user requested.  This is a shot in the dark, but I hope it helps nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Use root relative URIs:

```
href="/foo/bar"
```

rather than absolute URIs:

```
href="http://example.com/foo/bar"
```

That way the document will be loaded from the same hostname.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> my references are to the domain name

?

If you load scripts in your page on http://servername (using `<script src=''>`), they will have access to everything on http://servername, even if they come from another domain.

However, if you try to make AJAX calls to the other domain, then you have a problem. You can use the trick explained by Christopher, ie making aliases to the domain.